# GetExportedValues<MyType> returns nothing, I can see the parts

Tags: mef, system.componentmodel

I have a strange MEF problem, I tested this in a test project and it all seems to work pretty well but for some reason not working in the real project

This is the exporting code

```
    public void RegisterComponents()
    {

        _registrationBuilder = new RegistrationBuilder();
         _registrationBuilder
            .ForTypesDerivedFrom(typeof(MyType))
            .SetCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)
            .Export();

        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(MyType).Assembly, _registrationBuilder));


        var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(PathToMyTypeDerived, _registrationBuilder);
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(directoryCatalog);

        _compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        _compositionContainer.ComposeParts();

        var exports = _compositionContainer.GetExportedValues<MyType>();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} exports in AppDomain {1}", exports.Count(), AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
    }
```

exports count is 0 :( Any ideas why?

IN the log file I have many of this

System.ComponentModel.Composition Information: 6 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'SomeOthertype' was ignored because it contains no exports.

Though I would think this is ok because I wasn' interested in exporting 'someOtherType'

UPDATE: I found this [link](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/389060) but after debuging over it I am not wiser but maybe I m not following up properly.

Thanks for any pointers

Cheers

Comment: What is CorePlugin? Does it derive from MyType?

Comment: it is MyType, I ll edit the code (I changed the names to make the problem more obvious)

Comment: BTW if I build with Roslyn this is picked up on the second time but I can't constantly change compilers :D

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem and [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2010/07/13/how-to-debug-and-diagnose-mef-failures.aspx) helped me a lot.

It describes different reasons why a resolve can fail. One of the more important ones is that the dependency of a dependency of the type you want to resolve is not registered.

What helped me a lot was the the trace output that gets written to the Output window when you debug your application. It describes exactly the reasons why a type couldn't be resolved.

Even with this output. you might need to dig a little bit, because I only got one level deep.

Example:

I wanted to resolve type A and I got a message like this:

> System.ComponentModel.Composition Warning: 1 : The ComposablePartDefinition 'Namespace.A' has been rejected. The composition remains unchanged. The changes were rejected because of the following error(s): The composition produced multiple composition errors, with 1 root causes. The root causes are provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.
>
> 1) No exports were found that match the constraint: 
>       ContractName    Namespace.IB
>       RequiredTypeIdentity    Namespace.IB
>
> Resulting in: Cannot set import 'Namespace.A..ctor (Parameter="b", ContractName="namespace.IB")' on part 'Namespace A'.
>   Element: Namespace.A..ctor (Parameter="b", ContractName="Namespace.IB") -->  Namespace.A -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...")

But I clearly saw a part for `Namespace.IB`. So, in the debugger, I tried to resolve that one. And I got another trace output. This time it told me that my implementation of `Namespace.IB` couldn't be resolved because for one of its imports there was a missing export, so basically the same message as above, just with different types. And this time, I didn't find a part for that missing import. Now I knew, which type was the real problem and figure out, why no registration happened for it.

Comment: I found the following to be useful: (1) disable *Just My Code* option in *Visual Studio*, (2) configure *Visual Studio* to break on all CLR exceptions, (3) run your application with the *Visual Studio* debugger attached (4) when the exception is raised: look at the `InnerException` for the root cause. This helped me identify why MEF sometimes failed to load a dependency.